# DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, localdate

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2017-02-02 08:59:12", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

It prints error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-02-02 08:59:12' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=59, NanoOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=12, MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, HourOfAmPm=8},ISO resolved to 2017-02-02 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Accoeding message looks like all values parsed correct, but anyway I see error.

How to make it working?

Comment: `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`? You indicate hours etc in your formatter

Comment: working fine by me!

Comment: The exception indicates that you try to parse to a `LocalDateTime`. The code you have in your question works

Comment: sorry, guys, corrected

Comment: The detail to note in the error message is `HourOfAmPm=8`. It does not say hour of day…

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I can only reproduce the exception you get when I try to parse to a `LocalDateTime`, so I assume that's what you want.

Your mistake is using `hh` (clock-hour-of-am-pm) instead of `HH` (hour-of-day). This works:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-02-02 08:59:12", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(ldt);
```

And prints:

```
2017-02-02T08:59:12
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was in year pattern, I used week based year `YYYY` instead of  `yyyy`